# C# Длина не может быть меньше нуля

Tags: c#

```
string[] text = new string[2];
```

При отладке выдает следующую ошибку:
"Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Длина не может быть меньше нуля."

```
int first = Page.IndexOf(leftText) + leftText.Length;
int last = Page.IndexOf(RightText, first);
string[] text = new string[2];
text[0] = Page.Substring(first, (last - first));
text[1] = Page.Remove(0, last);
```

Comment: я не могу понять, почему такое появляется..

Comment: нужно больше кода..... в основном после все этой конструкции. ибо ругается не на эту строку, не так ли?

Comment: ох, грузить придется очень много.. попробую вытащить самое нужное

Comment: Ну а что вы хотели? Показать объявление переменной и все должны догадаться где у вас конкретно в коде проблема?...... или перевести вам сообщение надо? тогда вам это ничего не даст

Comment: `int first = Page.IndexOf(leftText) + leftText.Length;
                int last = Page.IndexOf(RightText, first);
                string[] text = new string[2];
                text[0] = Page.Substring(first, (last - first));
                text[1] = Page.Remove(0, last);`

Comment: Page.Substring(first, (last - first)); мб тут

Comment: `string[] text = new string[2] { "", "" };
                int first = Page.IndexOf(leftText) + leftText.Length;
                int last = Page.IndexOf(RightText, first);`

Comment: это строки, все эти переменные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IndexOf` возвращает -1, если нет вхождения. Вот и получается дальше отрицательная длина.

Comment: и точно, путем перелопачивания кода, нашел, что случайно в функцию не тот параметр передается! Спасибо)